# Не работает валидатор длины в mongoose

Tags: валидация, mongoose

Нашла такой же вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58831178/minlength-validator-not-working-in-mongoose, но у меня всё с этим в порядке, а валидатор всё равно не работает.
Файл note.js:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false)

const url = process.env.MONGODB_URI

console.log('connecting to', url)

mongoose.connect(url)

  .then(result => {
    console.log('connected to MongoDB')
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('error connecting to MongoDB:', error.message)
  })

const noteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  content: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 5,
    required: true
  },
  important: Boolean
})
mySchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

noteSchema.set('toJSON', {
  transform: (document, returnedObject) => {
    returnedObject.id = returnedObject._id.toString()
    delete returnedObject._id
    delete returnedObject.__v
  }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Note', noteSchema)
```

Фрагмент index.js:

```js
app.post('/api/notes', (request, response, next) => {
  const body = request.body

  const note = new Note({
    content: body.content,
    important: body.important || false,
  })
  note.save()
    .then(savedNote => {
      response.json(savedNote)
    })
    .catch(error => next(error))
})

app.put('/api/notes/:id', (request, response, next) => {
  const {
    content,
    important
  } = request.body

  Note.findByIdAndUpdate(
      request.params.id, {
        content,
        important
      }, {
        new: true,
        runValidators: true,
        context: 'query'
      }
    )
    .then(updatedNote => {
      response.json(updatedNote)
    })
    .catch(error => next(error))
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После удаления плагина plugin(uniqueValidator) всё заработало. Думаю причина в том, что в версии mongoose"^8.0.4" уже есть встроенный валидатор.